# How to get renewed Apple Development Centificate into Provisioning Center

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning

My Development Certificate is about to expire. I took action and renewed my membership
by paying the amount and now have the mail from Apple stating "Thank you for renewing your Apple Developer Program". There are a couple of details like new expiration date and my team id.

Still when i logon with my apple id into the provisioning center I dont see my new certificate listed there. So my question is, what do I have to do to get it in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this a few days ago. I had to go to the provisioning portal and generate a new one. For Distribution I had to revoke the existing one.

This didn't seem right but it was the only way I found.

Comment: Under "Certificates" I just dont have a Button "create" or "update" or similar. So i don't know how to do that...

Comment: I had to Revoke my old one. Didn't like doing it, it isn't at all clear what happens to existing apps when you do that.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I issued an support Request to Apple to clear what happens to existing apps when revoking old certificates. I'll update the thread once they let me know.

Comment: There wasn't any response from Apple up until now. Yet I can confirm your answer, hence I marked it as accepted. Older builds are still running until the old certificate run out.